# org.kodein.di.Kodein$NotFoundException: 2 bindings found that match bind()

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection, kodein

I have an interface `WordsDataSource` using which I have implemented two concrete classes namely `WordsLocalDataSource` that deals with local database and another `WordsRemoteDataSource` that deals with manipulating data online on the server. The problem is when I try to inject the two classes in repository class using abstract class name `WordsDataSource` like

```
DefaultWordsRepository(
     private val wordsRemoteDataSource: WordsDataSource,
     private val wordsLocalDataSource: WordsDataSource) {
```

And adding dependencies in Application class like

```
class WordsApplication : Application(), KodeinAware {

    override val kodein = Kodein.lazy {
        import(androidXModule(this@WordsApplication))
        bind() from singleton { WordsDatabase.getInstance(instance()) }
        bind<WordsDao>() with singleton { instance<WordsDatabase>().wordsDao() }
        bind() from singleton { WordsLocalDataSource(instance()) }
        bind() from singleton { WordsRemoteDataSource() }
        bind<WordsRepository>() with singleton { DefaultWordsRepository(instance(), instance()) }
        bind() from provider { ViewModelFactory(instance()) }
    }
```

Then upon running the app I encounter the following issue in the logcat

```
org.kodein.di.Kodein$NotFoundException: 2 bindings found that match bind<WordsDataSource>() with ?<WordsFragment>().? { ? }:
        bind<WordsLocalDataSource>() with singleton { WordsLocalDataSource }
        bind<WordsRemoteDataSource>() with singleton { WordsRemoteDataSource }
```

I have tried the workaround for this by simply declaring the variables by their respective concrete class names like

```
DefaultWordsRepository(
     private val wordsRemoteDataSource: WordsRemoteDataSource,
     private val wordsLocalDataSource: WordsLocalDataSource) {
```

But still want to know whether or not is there any way to resolve the issue.

I am using the following dependencies for kodein

```
implementation "org.kodein.di:kodein-di-generic-jvm:6.3.3"
implementation "org.kodein.di:kodein-di-framework-android-x:6.3.3"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have done it the right way by writing the explicit types:

```
DefaultWordsRepository(
     private val wordsRemoteDataSource: WordsRemoteDataSource,
     private val wordsLocalDataSource: WordsLocalDataSource)
```

When working with sub-types we cannot know what kind of implementation  to choose. Writing

```
DefaultWordsRepository(
     private val wordsRemoteDataSource: WordsDataSource,
     private val wordsLocalDataSource: WordsDataSource)
```

Doesn't cannot find if you want both sub-types or twice the `WordsRemoteDataSource` or `WordsLocalDataSource`. Thus, you need to explicit define your types. Even, we could put `WordsRemoteDataSource` in the property `wordsLocalDataSource`, as we cannot rely on variable names.

Comment: Okay, I see. Thanks, @romainbsl. I shall do the same.